# Converting a structured string to an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say I have a string like so:

```
var myStr = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
```

How can I convert it to something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I'm trying to do this using the following command:

```
JSON.parse(myStr)
```

However, I get an error. What's the right way to do this?
Moreover, can the same method be used for structured strings containing non-numbers? Like the following:

```
var myStr2 = "[cats, dogs, elephants]"
```

EDIT:

To be specific, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data
```

The string part is something like this:

```
[16 Sep,16 Sep,16 Sep,16 Sep,16 Sep,16 Sep,16 Sep]
```

So I dont really understand why I get this error.

Comment: I don’t get an error. `myStr2` needs to look like `'["cats", "dogs", "elephants"]'` in order for `JSON.parse` to work.

Comment: The string should be in a proper *JSON* format. In your first case you could not have such error. Only in case 2 and 3 you have problems, as the strings should be quoted as Nour Yasein suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to convert the string to array.Remove the brackets and split the string with comma.

```
var myStr = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
var arr = myStr.replace(/^\[|\]$/g,'').split(','); // converted array
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write it like so

```
var myStr2 = '["cats","dogs","elephants"]' ; 
obj = JSON.parse(myStr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try     `var array = JSON.parse("[" + myStr + "]");` This will give you an array [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

For an array with number [this](https://jsbin.com/kezocavuja/edit?js,console) works:

```
var myStr = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
var array = JSON.parse(myStr);

console.log(array);
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```